# How to reference a file from within Azure Functions in JAVA?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I've looked at the 5 other questions that asked the same thing, but none of them are working. I am able to deploy a folder of resources to the `wwwroot` where the runnable `.jar` lives for the function.

`/resources` is in same directory as the `.jar`.

I have tried bundling the resources with the jar path, and accessing using `this.getClass().getResource('resources/file.txt')`, but it doesn't work on the cloud environment for some reason, and also, an SDK I'm working with requires me to be using the native, Java `File` api.

For reference, here is a screenshot of what the structure looks like after deploying the Azure Function:

[image: screenshot of azure function]

As can be seen above, that `.jar` file needs to access the `/resources` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and come up with this workaround in order to have it working both locally and on azure:

```
    String filename = "myfile.dat";
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = MyFunction.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
        if (stream == null) {
            ctx.getLogger().severe(format("file [%s] not found", certificateName));
            ctx.getLogger().warning("assuming azure environment, using absolute path /home/site/wwwroot/" + filename);
            stream = new FileInputStream("/home/site/wwwroot/" + filename);
        }
     //...rest of the code, catch clause...
```

The `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream` stream will correctly read the files you place in `src/main/resources` and the `FileInputStream` will look at the absolute path in your deployment.